# How does readLine() in BufferedReader works?

Tags: java, input, bufferedreader, readline

In java the `BufferedReader` has a method called `readLine()`, so I'm wondering how it works when I click on "Open Declaration", this is what pops up:

```
public String readLine() throws IOException {
       return readLine(false);
}
```

Then, I clicked on the "Open Declaration" on the `readLine(false)`, and this pops up:

```
String readLine(boolean ignoreLF) throws IOException {
        StringBuffer s = null;
        int startChar;

        synchronized (lock) {
            ensureOpen();
            boolean omitLF = ignoreLF || skipLF;

        bufferLoop:
            for (;;) {

                if (nextChar >= nChars)
                    fill();
                if (nextChar >= nChars) { /* EOF */
                    if (s != null && s.length() > 0)
                        return s.toString();
                    else
                        return null;
                }
                boolean eol = false;
                char c = 0;
                int i;

                /* Skip a leftover '\n', if necessary */
                if (omitLF && (cb[nextChar] == '\n'))
                    nextChar++;
                skipLF = false;
                omitLF = false;

            charLoop:
                for (i = nextChar; i < nChars; i++) {
                    c = cb[i];
                    if ((c == '\n') || (c == '\r')) {
                        eol = true;
                        break charLoop;
                    }
                }

                startChar = nextChar;
                nextChar = i;

                if (eol) {
                    String str;
                    if (s == null) {
                        str = new String(cb, startChar, i - startChar);
                    } else {
                        s.append(cb, startChar, i - startChar);
                        str = s.toString();
                    }
                    nextChar++;
                    if (c == '\r') {
                        skipLF = true;
                    }
                    return str;
                }

                if (s == null)
                    s = new StringBuffer(defaultExpectedLineLength);
                s.append(cb, startChar, i - startChar);
            }
        }
    }
```

But I don't get this part:

```
synchronized (lock) {
            ensureOpen();
            boolean omitLF = ignoreLF || skipLF;

        bufferLoop:
            for (;;) {

                if (nextChar >= nChars)
                    fill();
                if (nextChar >= nChars) { /* EOF */
                    if (s != null && s.length() > 0)
                        return s.toString();
                    else
                        return null;
                }
```

can someone please explain, or if there is a source link, please send it to me, since I can't find any link about it.

Comment: We _could_ try and annotate the whole method for you, but ... why? What are you trying to achieve, why are you trying to understand the implementation of this specific method? Is there something specific you're looking for?

Comment: @PetrJaneček enmmm... Because I want to know how it works, I mean, why do humans don't want to die? I just want to know it, there is no purpose.

Comment: This is not the kind of question that are answered here. Take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: What *specifically* don't you understand? Your question is too broad. --- *"can't quite understand the first several lines"* Ok, well, to begin with: `StringBuffer s = null;` declares a local variable named `s`, of type `StringBuffer`, and initializes the variable to `null`. Better? Do you now understand what the statement does? Oh, that was not the statement you were asking about? How were we supposed to know that? Do you want us to waste all our free time explaining everything in detail, even all the stuff you already know. Well, we're not going to do that.

Comment: *Hint:* `bufferLoop:` is a **label**. Do a web search to learn more, if your question was about that.